# LOGSTASH Grok , logstash-filter-json

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok

I have this log. I want to parse it with grok.

```
2017-05-29 00:00:12,145 INFO Identity:UserID=null;Correlation:BPID=null,BSID=f4dbd7f5-94e5-4c9d-bde6-ef0b6b0c6203,MID=null,PID=1494396441974578728;BUSINESS:InkassoService;2017_1;gibZahlstatus;231;OK;PID:1494396441974578728;UserID:xv86e0p;Channel:rv24;IDs:;ESBExecution:pid=1494396441975960958,workflow=Public/InkassoService/2017_1/gibZahlstatus/gibZahlstatus.wrf,status=1,proxyduration=200,workflowduration=200;
```

I've tried this pattern but without result:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},\s*%{INT}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:log-level} :%{WORD:Identity}\S+%{WORD};:%{WORD:Correlation}\S+%{WORD},(?<BSID>[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12},(?<MID>[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}),(?<PID>[A-Fa-f0-9]{18});
:%{WORD:BUSINESS};%{YEAR}_%{INT};%{NOTSPACE:RUF};%{NUMBER:server_response};%{NOTSPACE:termination_state};(?<PID>[A-Fa-f0-9]{18});(:%{HOSTNAME:UserID});(:%{HOSTNAME:Channel});%{NOTSPACE:IDS};:%{WORD:ESBExecution}\S+%{WORD},%{WORD}\S+%{URIPATH:uri},%{NUMBER:status},(?:%{BASE10NUM:workflowduration});(?:%{BASE10NUM:proxyduration})
```

Comment: When I'm building complex filters in Logstash, I found this site to be helpful. http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Also look at https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns. You will see that `SECOND` in the spec can contain commas. So the timestamp is all of `2017-05-29 00:00:12,145`. You are thinking `145` is a separate integer. That's at least one issue.

Comment: I wouldn't capture the strings "Identity", "Correlation", "status", etc., but only capture the assignment values. A few other log lines would be helpful in case some of the strings do not repeat in every log line. Captured variables cannot have a "-" in the name (`log-level` should be `log_level`). You also have some captures out of order, (`proxyduration` and `workflowduration`). See my first comment and use the grok debugger, start with the first capture and add the rest one by one.

Comment: Hallo thanks can you give me   example how can i define A:B=100

Comment: I tried in  debugger grok but no result how can i add Worksflow=public/A/B in regular expression i am beginner in this topic

Comment: You need clarify what you expect the resulting JSON to look like. Here's another page about RE's as used in Logstash -> https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE

Comment: An example of why you should include expected output is the expression
`workflow=(?<workflow>\S+/\S+/\S+)` will parse `workflow=public/A/B` into `{
  "workflow": [
    [
      "public/A/B"
    ]
  ]
}'

But that may not be what you want.